# What are the requirements to have the change your background feature enabled in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: privacy, video-conference, microsoft-teams

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-background-for-a-teams-meeting-f77a2381-443a-499d-825e-509a140f4780 mentions:

> Note: If you don't see this option in the menu, the feature might not be available on your device yet.

What are the requirements to have the change your background feature enabled in Microsoft Teams on Android? I have a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android and I don't see the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of late March 2021, Microsoft Teams for Android doesn't have "blur background".

However, per [MSPowerUser.com - Background blur is coming to Microsoft Teams for Android](https://mspoweruser.com/background-blur-microsoft-teams-android/) which has a link in the article to a support forum, such a feature is pending/planned, but with no definitive timeline.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tomsguide.com/news/galaxy-s21-features-to-enable claims one can change the background on a meeting in MS Teams on Android with a Samsung Galaxy S21:

> Galaxy S21 features: Video effects. With the Galaxy S21, Samsung has introduced a new feature for video calls. Simply called Video Call Effects, it lets you add blur, a solid color, or an image to your background while on a chat. In this age of social distancing, Video Call Effects spice up your video calls.

https://redd.it/p726we claims that MS Teams the virtual  background option with Xiaomi Pocophone F1.